# Не отображаются null-строки при LEFT JOIN

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3, join

UPD убрал одну несущественную строку.

На python использую sqlite3 для работы с таблицами. 
Пытаюсь объединить данные с 3х таблиц и сосчитать количество строк статистики в сочетании данных с первых двух:

```
SELECT pd.d_id, pd.l_id, COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT p.id AS l_id, d.id AS d_id 
FROM people p LEFT JOIN duties d ON p.project_id = d.project_id) pd 
LEFT JOIN stats st ON pd.l_id = st.login_id AND pd.d_id = st.duty_id
GROUP BY pd.d_id, pd.l_id;
```

При этом вижу, что COUNT верно подсчитывает количество строк, НО не выводит количество = 0, если оно таковое, то есть выводит только то, что есть. Вроде как LEFT JOIN должен-таки такое учитывать.

Мне нужно:

```
pd.d_id | pd.l_id | COUNT(*) 
1       | 12      | 1
1       | 11      | 1
1       | 10      | 0
2       | 12      | 2
2       | 11      | 0
2       | 10      | 4
...
```

Выводится мне:

```
pd.d_id | pd.l_id | COUNT(*) 
1       | 12      | 1
1       | 11      | 1
2       | 12      | 2
2       | 10      | 4
...
```

что делаю не так?

Comment: Интересно, а без WHERE что будет? Как понимаю, в интересующих строках st.project_id будет NULL

Comment: При каких данных запрос возвращает такой результат?

Comment: *что делаю не так?* В качестве самой левой таблицы основного запроса должны быть таблица или подзапрос, возвращающие все возможные пары значений `(people.id, duties.id)`. Что-то вроде `SELECT DISTINCT p.id, d.id FROM people p, dutied d`. Тогда все они и в выходном наборе будут присутствовать - в т.ч. и с нулями.

Comment: @Akina Вот как раз проблема в том, что сам `SELECT p.id AS l_id, d.id AS d_id 
FROM people p LEFT JOIN duties d ON p.project_id = d.project_id` возвращает все комбинации `(people.id, duties.id)` , но вот в выходе их почему-то нет...

Comment: без группировки все данные выводятся?

Comment: Не верю. Создайте fiddle или хотя бы воспроизводящий проблему набор скриптов.

Comment: @СмоляноеЧучелко да, прошу прощения, эта строка затесалась случайно, она не несет никакой нагрузки без неё всё так же не работает)

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Нет, в этих строках тоже нет null-значений, проверял, да

Comment: если избавиться от подзапроса? зачем он вообще нужен?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Он нужен, чтобы всегда было сочетание, количество данных по которому и считается. Но его можно убрать в пользу того же LEFT JOIN, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Ох, друзья. Мой косяк. Знал, что проблема в чём-то простом. 
В общем Считал я по всей строке, а не по той части, которая должна отсутствовать, в итоге на тех местах, на которых должен был быть 0, была 1.

Что я вчера видел и как считал столбцы уже не пойму. Много всего перепробовал, видимо перепуталось в голове.

В итоге вот такая штука заработала:

```
SELECT pd.d_id, pd.l_id, COUNT(st.login_id)
FROM (
SELECT p.id AS l_id, d.id AS d_id 
FROM people p LEFT JOIN duties d ON p.project_id = d.project_id) pd 
LEFT JOIN stats st ON pd.l_id = st.login_id AND pd.d_id = st.duty_id
GROUP BY pd.d_id, pd.l_id;
```

Изи. @Akina cпасибо, что вселил уверенность в том, что не может такого быть (сам так думал, но всякое бывает), а то, казалось, что где-то в самой sqlite бага...